# Spark-Plugin for custom dynamic metrics

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on custom spark metrics using the SparkPlugin. I'm able to register static metrics

```
package com.mavencode.example.plugin

import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry
import org.apache.spark.api.plugin.{DriverPlugin, ExecutorPlugin, PluginContext, SparkPlugin}

class CustomMetricSparkPlugin extends SparkPlugin {

  override def driverPlugin(): DriverPlugin = null

  override def executorPlugin(): ExecutorPlugin = new ExecutorPlugin {
    override def init(ctx: PluginContext, extraConf: java.util.Map[String, String]): Unit = {
      val metricRegistry = ctx.metricRegistry()
      metricRegistry.register("blacklisted_count", EventMetricPlugin.blacklistedEventCounter)
      metricRegistry.register("avro_json_parser_duration", EventMetricPlugin.avroParserTimer)
      metricRegistry.register("avro_json_parser_partition_size", EventMetricPlugin.avroParserEventsPerPartition)
      metricRegistry.register("avro_json_parser_errors", EventMetricPlugin.avroParserErrorCounter)
     
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would like to register dynamic metrics so I can update the metrics for the dynamic event `<event_name>.blacklisted_count`

```
metricRegistry.register("<event_name>.blacklisted_count", EventMetricPlugin.blacklistedEventCounter)
```

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: It's not clear to me, what is the issue: from where would you get the dynamic event name? Why string concatenation/interpolation is not enough?

Comment: For example, in `mapPartition` where we have some custom code that parses different event types.